# How can I explicitly redirect to an automatically-generated `error` route?

Tags: ember.js

It seems I can explicitly visit/redirect to an auto-created `loading` route, but not an `error` route. Is there any reason for this? Or way to work around it?

By "auto-created", I mean I have created loading and error templates, but haven't explicitly created routes or defined them in the router. The [Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) explain that this will create a loading route, and [implies (but does not explicitly state)](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-error-code-substates) that the same should be true for error routes.

The error I'm seeing looks as though the route doesn't exist:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
vendor.js:28585DEBUG: Ember      : 1.8.1
vendor.js:28585DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.12
vendor.js:28585DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
vendor.js:28585DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.2
vendor.js:28585DEBUG: -------------------------------
vendor.js:28585Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/error' did not match any routes in your application
    at new Error (unknown source)
    at Error.EmberError (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:27463:23)
    at Object.assert (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:17077:15)
    at http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:39714:17
    at tryCatch (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:60519:16)
    at invokeCallback (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:60531:17)
    at http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:62430:13
    at http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:42647:9
    at http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:13891:18
    at Object.flush (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:13961:15)
vendor.js:17077Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/error' did not match any routes in your application
```

But it is listed as an available route:

```
Ember.keys(Onboarding.Router.router.recognizer.names)
["loading", "error", ..., "index", "application"]
```

Despite this, explicitly adding it to the router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  ...
  this.route("error");
});
```

does fix the issue.

Am I doing something silly? Or is this intended behavior?

*Edit:*

JSBin to illustrate the difference: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yicijayiri/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and found a helpful tip at: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/error-route-must-now-be-explicitly-included-in-router-intended-behavior/6943

Upon testing, this led me to understand that in your example, you can link to the error page (without explicitly defining an error route) by adding an expected argument. Since you are not using the argument, it does not matter what it is. Adding a second argument in the link-to works on your example: `{{link-to "error page" "error" "A string"}}`

Here is some additional information that might be helpful. If you wish to transitionTo the error route, it works similarly if you pass a second argument.

```
this.transitionTo('error', 'Error'); // OR
this.intermediateTransitionTo('error', 'Error');
```

Now, if you want to use the argument in the error message, you could use an error template like the following:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="error">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</script>
```

With this template, when you use transitionTo or intermediateTransitionTo, you would need to pass an error object as the argument: `this.transitionTo('error', new Error('My custom error message.'));`

Additionally, if you want to also pass in a unique Error name, you could do this:

```
var errorObj = new Error('My customer error message');
errorObj.name = 'Custom Error';
this.transitionTo('error', errorObj);
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed that Discuss question. It's still not clear to me *why* it was decided that the error routes shouldn't be accessible by URL, but your answer is very helpful in explaining how to make use of the feature as it exists. Thanks! (also, welcome to SO -- great first answer!)